# drag/drop file from file explorer to browser webelement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to drag/drop file from file explorer into browser webelement. 
I cannot use file upload method since it's strictly a drag/drop test. Also cannot use standard Actions class dragandrop method since the source element is the file explorer and not a browser element.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with Selenium WebDriver for the exact reason you mentioned, File Explorer is not a browser window. You'd need to use another automation tool, such as AutoIt, which is beyond my capabilities at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial of Sikuli, you can manage the system windows too with it.
http://imobiliarerolabs.tumblr.com/post/64859016557/how-to-use-sikuli-when-automating-tests-with-selenium